# Execute UNIX shell command with TCL version 8.5 commands

Tags: shell, unix, tcl, exec, sha1sum

I'm trying to calculate the SHA1 of different TCL scripts in a folder for version checking (*my TCL version is 8.5*). I want to do this from within one of the TCL scripts, and print this info into a separate file. I thought I could do something like this:

```
set repoDir "some/repo/dir"
set scripts_hash [cd $repoDir/scripts; exec sha1sum ./* | sha1sum]
puts $file $scripts_hash
```

However, exec doesn't allow this? How can I execute a sha1sum shell command from within a .tcl script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either explicitly loop over each element, or put them all together. Here's a loop option:

```
# ... open $file
set repoDir "some/repo/dir"
foreach f [glob -directory $repoDir -- "*"] {
  puts $file [exec sha1sum $f]
}
close $file
```

and here's a one-shot call to `sha1sum`:

```
# ... open $file
set repoDir "some/repo/dir"
puts $file [exec sha1sum {*}[glob -directory $repoDir -- "*"]]
close $file
```

The `{*}` prefix forces TCL (v8.5+) to expand each of the resulting `glob` list items to become individual arguments for `sha1sum`.

Comment: As a (worse) alternative, launch a shell to expand the glob: `exec sh -c {sha1sum ./* | sha1sum}`